# tool/library to store passwords for many accounts to be shared between team members

Tags: password-manager

We have fairly large infrastructure to run our services - one of the component for running  GUI enabled tests on windows.

There are many places the plain text password is used such as "remote desktop to windows machine" , login to a default account (windows).  We now need to change this account every couple of weeks.  Is there a solution to manage this effectively?

Needs:

- Store password in single place, encrypted - we will reset password and only update here
- Fetch it using a API (say REST api call using token?)
- Commercial or Free is fine

What complicates the situation is the number of service accounts-  we have about 50  service accounts (couple of the accounts are having administrative rights on machines; most are plain accounts), team size is less than 10.

Comment: What scale are we talking about? You want to manage 50 secrets; how many users do you expect?

Comment: @ Vlastimil Ovčáčík - less than 10 - for now

Comment: In that case I guess [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) by HashiCorp would be overkill. If you really want API access to the secrets, maybe give it a try anyway. Otherwise I would use some low-tech solution, like encrypted file on network storage.

Answer (score 2):

[ccrypt](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/) is a simple GPLed command-line encryption tool. You could store the passwords in a text file, encrypt it with ccrypt, and then get the decrypted version remotely by calling `ccdecrypt` over SSH (or, fetch the encrypted version and then decrypt it locally).

Comment: Jayan seems to need API access to the secrets...

Answer (score 2):

[Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) open source secret management system. In your scenario it would basically work as online password manager. The value of this solution lies in this imho:

- you will teach users to use `vault` to securely fetch current Windows password

  - users don't need to manage this password, as they can always fetch it again
- you can change the secret without notifying users, because they get up to date credential next time they call `vault`

I also like that [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) is single binary which makes deployment easy. Go ahead and read their [Your First Secret](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/first-secret.html) tutorial.